# In a C*-algebra, put $a^*a \sim aa^*$. Transitivity fails?

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Idle curiosity drove me to wonder about the following question. Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. Define a binary relation $\sim$ on the cone $A^{\geq 0}$ of positive elements by putting $x \sim y$ whenever there is an $a \in A$ such that $x = a^*a$ and $y = aa^*$. This is just like Murray-von Neumann equivalence but for arbitrary positive elements instead of projections.

The relation $\sim$ is reflexive since any positive $x$ can be written $x = (\sqrt{x})^* \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x} (\sqrt{x})^*$ where $\sqrt{x}$ is the unique positive square root of $x$. It is symmetric since if $x = a^* a$ and $y = aa^*$ then $x = bb^*$ and $y = b^*b$ where $b=a^*$.

I see no obvious reason for $\sim$ to be transitive. I suspect it is not, but I couldn't come up with a counterexample.

**Some observations:**

- As 5pm points out below, if $A$ is unital and $x,y \in A$ are invertible, then $x \sim y$ if and only if $y = uxu^*$ for some unitary $u$. It follows that the restriction of $\sim$ to the invertible elements of $A$ is an equivalence relation.
- It is an equivalence relation in the case $A=B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. Indeed, if $x = a^* a$ and $y = aa^*$ then, polar decomposing $a$ as $u \sqrt{a^*a}$, we get that $y = u x u^*$ for a partial isometry $u$ with initial space $\overline{\mathrm{ran}(x)}$ and final space $\overline{\mathrm{ran}(y)}$. Since the composition of partial isometries with compatible supporting subspaces is another partial isometry, we get the transitivity.

**Some more observations:**

- If it occurs that, $$ \text{for every $a \in A$, there exists $b \in A$ such that $aa^* = b^*(a^*a)b$,}$$ then $\sim$ is clearly transitive. The latter occurs, for example, when every element $a \in A$ has a "weak polar decomposition" $a = b \sqrt{a^*a}$ for any $b \in B$. In particular, existence of polar decompositions suffices to prove $\sim$ is transitive.
- We can still have $\sim$ transitive if the above condition fails. For example, if $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is nonvanishing, then there is no $g \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ with $fg = f$. Obviously $\sim$ is transitive in commutative C*-algebras.

Comment: The relation is transitive on invertible elements, since for them it amounts to being unitarily equivalent. Indeed, $x=a^*a$ implies that $u=ax^{-1/2}$ is a unitary, hence $y=uxu^*$.

Comment: @5pm: I think there's something not quite right about that comment since if $a$ is the unilateral shift on $\ell^2$ then $x = a^*a$ is the identity, but $ax^{-1/2} = a$ is not a unitary. And of course the identity mapping cannot be unitarily equivalent to the proper projection which is $aa^*$ in this case.

Comment: Repeat: The relation is transitive **on invertible elements**, since for them it amounts to...

Comment: @5pm: OK, agreed. If $x,y$ are **both** invertible, then yes: $x \sim y$ if and only if $x,y$ are unitarily equivalent. My previous comment points out that an invertible $x$ can still have $x \sim y$ for noninvertible $y$ I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out! The answer seems to be that transitivity holds. I would appreciate any feedback on my proof. Let $A$ be an arbitrary C*-algebra. Given positive elements $x,y \in A$ and $a \in A$, I will write $x \sim^a y$ to mean that $x = a^*a$ and $y =aa^*$.

> **Lemma.** If $x \sim^a y$, then there is a factorization $a = a_1 x^{1/4}$ such that $x^{1/2} \sim^{a_1} y^{1/2}$.
>
> **Proof.**  Without loss of generality, $A \subset B(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. Perform polar decomposition in $B(H)$ to write $a= w x^{1/2}$ where $w$ is a uniquely determined partial isometry whose supporting projection $w^* w$ equals the closed range of $x^{1/2}$. Now it may be that $w \notin A$, but an easy polynomial approximation argument shows that $a_1 = wx^{1/4} \in A$. So we have the factorization $a = a_1 x^{1/4}$. Observe $a_1^* a_1 = x^{1/4} w^* w x^{1/4} = x^{1/4} x^{1/4} = x^{1/2}$.  Meanwhile, $(a_1a_1^*)^2 = a_1 (a_1^* a_1)a_1^* = w x^{1/4} x^{1/2} x^{1/4} w^* = (w x^{1/2})(w x^{1/2})^* = aa^* = y$ so that $a_1 a_1^* = y^{1/2}$.

Now we can prove the main result.

> **Theorem.** The relation $\sim$ is transitive.
>
> **Proof.** Suppose positive elements $x,y,z$ have $x \sim^a y \sim^b z$ for $a,b \in A$. By the lemma, we have factorizations $a = a_1 x^{1/4}$ and $b = b_1 x^{1/4}$ such that $x^{1/2} \sim^{a_1} y^{1/2} \sim^{b_1} z$. We shall see that $x \sim^{b_1 a_1} z$. Indeed:
>   $$ (b_1a_1)^*(b_1a_1) = a_1^* b_1^* b_1 a_1 = a_1^* y^{1/2} a_1 = a_1^* a_1 a_1^* a_1 = x^{1/2} x^{1/2} = x$$
>   $$ (b_1a_1)(b_1a_1)^* = b_1 a_1 a_1^* b_1^* = b_1 y^{1/2} b_1^*= (b_1 y^{1/4})(b_1 y^{1/4})^* = bb^*  = z.$$

Comment: In the proof of the first theorem, you wrote $$ a_{1}^{\ast} a_{1} = x^{1/4} w^{\ast} w x^{1/4} = x^{1/4} x^{1/4} = x^{1/2}. $$ It isn’t immediately clear to me why $ w^{\ast} w x^{1/4} = x^{1/4} $ should follow from $ w^{\ast} w x^{1/2} = x^{1/2} $.

Comment: The reason that $w^*w x^{1/2} = x^{1/2}$ is that $w^*w$ is orthogonal projection onto $\overline{ \mathrm{ran} x^{1/2}}$. Here $\overline{ \mathrm{ran} x^{1/2}}=\overline{ \mathrm{ran} x^{1/4}}$. In general, the range of a positive operator $P$ and it's positive square root have the same closure (obviously $\ker P^{1/2} \subset \ker P$ and conversely if $Px = 0$ then $\|P^{1/2}x\|^2 = \langle Px,x\rangle = 0$ so $\ker P = \ker P^{1/2}$. So, the claim follows from $\overline{ \mathrm{ran} T} = (\ker T)^{bot}$.)

Comment: Yes. My comment was simply a prompt to you to provide some explanation for that fact, which isn’t immediately obvious. Further, as $$ a = w x^{1/2} = w x^{1/4} x^{1/4}, $$ you can simply write $ a_{1} = w x^{1/4} $ without the need of mentioning any polynomial approximation. Otherwise, the proof looks watertight. Good job! :)

Comment: @Haskell: Thanks for the input. To clarify, the reason for the 
"polynomial approximation" is not to show $a_1x^{1/4} = a$. This is clear, as you say, from the definition of $a_1$. The point is to show $a_1 \in A$ rather than just $B(H)$. The idea of the argument is that $x^{1/4}$ can be approximated by polynomials in $x^{1/2}$ with no constant term and that such polynomials when multiplied on the left by $w$ land in $C^*(a) \subset A$ (since $a = wx^{1/2}$ can be factored out on the left leaving only a polynomial in $x^{1/2}$).

Comment: I get your point now, Mike. Yes, it’s important to show that $ a_{1} \in A $ because it’ll be used to establish an equivalence between $ x^{1/2} $ and $ y^{1/2} $ within $ A $ itself, and you certainly don’t want to step outside of $ A $ into $ B(\mathcal{H}) \setminus A $ in order to do that. It’s a clever argument! :) Once again, impressive job!

Comment: @Mike: The equivalence relation that you have been contemplating is related to the Cuntz-Pedersen equivalence relation. Let $ a,b \in A_{\geq 0} $. We say that **$ a $ and $ b $ are Cuntz-Pedersen equivalent**, symbolically expressed as $ a \sim_{\text{CP}} b $, if and only if there exist $ x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} \in A $ such that $$ a = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{\ast} x_{i} \quad \text{and} \quad b = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} x_{i}^{\ast}. $$ One must then show that $ \sim_{\text{CP}} $ is indeed an equivalence relation. See [here](http://www.recercat.net/bitstream/handle/2072/3738/Pr711.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: @Leonard: Interesting, thanks for the info. I guess one advantage of the CP relation is that it is obviously true that $a + b \sim_{CP} a' + b'$ if $a \sim_{CP} a'$ and $b \sim_{CP} b'$ so the quotient $A_{\geq 0} / \sim_{CP}$ is naturally a semigroup. I'm not sure if the relation in the problem respects addition. Maybe I should post another problem?

Comment: Well actually, of course $\sim$ does not respect addition since Murray-Von Neumann equivalence already does not. However, it's not difficult to show $\sim$ does respect "orthogonal sums" i.e. if $x,y,x',y' \in A_{\geq 0}$ with $xy = x'y' = 0$ and $x \sim x', y \sim y'$ then $x+y \sim x' + y'$.